# Use Ramda's clone in pipe in a type-safe way

Tags: node.js, typescript, ramda.js, definitelytyped

I'd like to use Ramda to clone and update objects in a type-safe way (inspired by [this idiom](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/update-as-you-copy-dont-mutate-case-classes/)) but I can't get it working in a type-safe way.

Updating a nested object works in a type-safe way perfectly fine:

```
interface Person {
  name: string
  department: {
    name: string
    budget: number
    manager?: string
  }
}
const personX: Person = {
  name: 'Foo Bar',
  department: {
    name: 'x',
    budget: 2000,
  },
}

const addManager = (name: string): (input: Person) => Person => assocPath([
  'department',
  'manager',
], name)
const x = addManager('Michael Scott')(personX) // x is of type `Person`
```

I can also successfully combine functions using `pipe` or `compose`:

```
const addManager = (name: string): (input: Person) => Person => assocPath([
  'department',
  'manager',
], name)
const increaseBudget = (budget: number): (input: Person) => Person => assocPath([
  'department',
  'budget',
], budget)
const addManagerAndUpdateBudget = pipe(addManager('MichaelScott'), increaseBudget(10000))
const x = addManagerAndUpdateBudget(personX) // x is still of type Person
```

However, as soon as I use `clone` it fails:

```
const addManager = (name: string): (input: Person) => Person => assocPath([
  'department',
  'manager',
], name)
const increaseBudget = (budget: number): (input: Person) => Person => assocPath([
  'department',
  'budget',
], budget)
const addManagerAndUpdateBudget = pipe(clone, addManager('MichaelScott'), increaseBudget(10000))
const x = addManagerAndUpdateBudget(personX) // Person is not assignable to readonly unknown[]
```

Might this be an issue with the types? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `R.pipe` (or `R.compose`) with other Ramda generic functions (such as `R.clone`) TS sometimes fails to infer the correct types, and the actual signature of the created function.

**Note**: I'm using Ramda - 0.28.0 and @types/ramda - 0.28.8.

In your case we want Ramda to use this signature - A list of arguments pass to the created function (`TArgs`), and then 3 return types of the piped functions (`R1`, `R2`, `R3`):

```
export function pipe<TArgs extends any[], R1, R2, R3>(
    f1: (...args: TArgs) => R1,
    f2: (a: R1) => R2,
    f3: (a: R2) => R3,
): (...args: TArgs) => R3;
```

Since Ramda doesn't infer them, we'll need to add them explicitly ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ramda-pipe-with-typescript-forked-db39wb?file=/src/index.ts)):

```
const addManagerAndUpdateBudget = pipe<[Person], Person, Person, Person>(
  clone,
  addManager('MichaelScott'),
  increaseBudget(10000)
);
```

Arguments - a tuple with a single `Person`, and each return value is also a `Person`. We need to state all of them, so that TS would use the specific signature we need.

Another option is explicitly type the 1st function in the pipe, so TS can use it to infer the other types ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ramda-pipe-with-typescript-forked-1kn4gc?file=/src/index.ts:500-635)):

```
const addManagerAndUpdateBudget = pipe(
  clone as (person: Person) => Person,
  addManager('MichaelScott'),
  increaseBudget(10000)
);
```

Comment: Indeed, that does the trick. I noticed that TS does not pick up the correct definition for `clone` but always the overloaded one (it also works when I change the order in the type definitions file). What I still don't get is why you'd put the first argument (TArgs) in brackets? Shouldn't that be just `Person` as well?

Comment: Look at the signature - `TArgs extends any[]`. It's an array of arguments, that is then applied via spread to the 1st function - `f1: (...args: TArgs) => R1,`.

Comment: Absolutely makes sense! I misread the function signature!

Comment: I've added another solution.

Comment: Thanks, feels a bit like cheating though with the `as` in it

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I'm one of Ramda's core team.)

---

The Ramda team does not have a great deal of expertise in TypeScript.  I've added the `definitelytyped` tag, as that project maintains the usual Ramda typings.

Not knowing TypeScript typings well, I don't understand why this doesn't work, as when I read the [`clone` definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ramda/index.d.ts#L402-L403):

```
export function clone<T>(value: T): T;
export function clone<T>(value: readonly T[]): T[];
```

and the relevant [`pipe` definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ramda/index.d.ts#L2063-L2067)

```
export function pipe<TArgs extends any[], R1, R2, R3>(
    f1: (...args: TArgs) => R1,
    f2: (a: R1) => R2,
    f3: (a: R2) => R3,
): (...args: TArgs) => R3;
```

everything looks right to me.  I wonder if you need to declare the resulting of `addManager` and `increaseBudget` as `Person`.  But that's just a guess, from a non-TS person.

---

I answered chiefly because I want to point out that for many uses, you will not need to use `clone` because `assocPath` already does the equivalent for any data it's altering.

```js
const person2 = increaseBudget  (10000) (person1)
person2 == person1 //=> false
person2 .department == person1 .department //=> false
```

Of course `assocPath` uses structural sharing where it can and does not do a full clone:

```js
const person2 = assocPath ('startDate', '2014-07-12') (person1)
person2 .department == person1 .department //=> true
```

But for many uses, especially if further modifications are done using Ramda or with other immutable techniques, `clone` is simply unnecessary.

-- Scott

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I knew that `assocPath` creates a (shallow) clone but as you stated, there are many use cases that actually require a deep clone. Regarding your suggestion: It also does not work when I specify the (return) types explicitly. I guess it's just the types that are wrong, because everything works as expected when I cast manually. I guess the overloaded function definition for `clone` is the real problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an issue with TypeScript not liking overloads and generics when used in HOFs - for functions with multiple overloads TypeScript simply tries the last one (and only the last one)